# How to show array of objects in TableView - swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

Hello can you help me I want to display in an TableView an array of objects but only one compoment of the array.

here my code:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let index = indexPath.row as Int

    for dep in autoCompleteDestino {
        DestinoInstancia.idDestino = dep.idDestino!
        DestinoInstancia.desDestino = dep.desDestino!
        autoCompleteDestino.append(dep)
    }

    print(autoCompleteDestino)
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: autoCompleteDestino[index])

    return cell
}
```

}

So..i want to show in this line, only the DestinoInstancia.desDestino = dep.desDestino!

```
cell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: autoCompleteDestino[index])
```

Currently shows me this way:

> MTiOS.Destinos(idDestino: Optional(1), desDestino: Optional("Asunción")), MTiOS.Destinos(idDestino: Optional(2), desDestino: Optional("Miami")), MTiOS.Destinos(idDestino: Optional(3), desDestino: Optional("Atenas")), MTiOS.Destinos(idDestino: Optional(5), desDestino: Optional("Madrid"))][image]

When i want to show me only:

> Asunción 
>   Miami
>   Atenas
>   Madrid

Please Help!

Comment: Looks like you are not unwrapping those optionals.

Comment: i think..yes, i unwrapping: DestinoInstancia.idDestino = dep.idDestino!
        DestinoInstancia.desDestino = dep.desDestino!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue lies in the String conversion and unwrapped optionals.

Try replacing this:

```
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: autoCompleteDestino[index])
```

With this:

```
    if let str = autoCompleteDestino[index].desDestino {
        cell.textLabel?.text = str
    }
```

This replacement safely unwraps the optional while also retrieving the correct string.

Comment: even...i don't need to loop the array...i need only this code:  if let str = autoCompleteDestino[index].desDestino {
            cell.textLabel?.text = str
        }

Comment: Glad I could help... I simplified the post a bit to make it a little clearer.